# Nextjs export (static page) gives me the wrong path in css background-images

Tags: next.js

After running next build and next export, I don't see images assigned in background-image in css. I discovered that the reason for this is a wrong path after doing the next export.
Image path after page export to static files:
file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/frontend/out/_next/static/css**/_next/static/media/logoR.8b482e024d38c471760fb327b4c4da3e.png**

(The bold font is the path that still doesn't exist in the file folder.)
But the real path is:
C:\Users\user\Documents\frontend\out\image\logoR.png

What do I need to do to make the path to the background-images fit correctly when doing the next export?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your image loader in your next.config.js file?

If not add this code in your next.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
        loader: "imgix",
        path: "",
    },
};
```

Make sure your images are inside the PUBLIC folder.